# An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tsx

I am new to Typescript and trying to build a react boilerplate for typescript. But cant import components which are in form '.tsx'.

My tsconfig file looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and my eslintrc looks like this :

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [2, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
        "linebreak-style": 0,
        "global-require": 0,
        "eslint linebreak-style": [0, "error", "windows"],
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "indent": [2, 2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you mean by "can't import components which are in form .tsx"? What error are you seeing? As a side note, you can try the [React + Typescript boilerplate](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) provided by Create React App, which is a decent place to start.

Comment: Can you clarify? `.tsx` is not a recognized browser language, so you're probably using a compiler like babel and/or webpack. That's likely what's choking on your `.tsx` files.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the tsconfig.json file and add paths options like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got this sorted yet, I am able to resolve this issue by adding a tsconfig.json file to the root directiory and then dropping the extension on the import.

Steps I took to resolve:

```
npm install typescript -g
tsc --init
```